# Measure of a set trigonometric Function

Tags: measure-theory

Can somebody Help me with this Problem?I have to find the measure of the set$\{x\in [0,1]:-x^{2}cos(\frac{1}{x})\ge 1\}$..I am completely stuck.Van you give an idea?Thanks!! I tried to find out the critical points of that Function in order to find the Minimum but it did Not work. The derivative is too complicated..

Comment: $-x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ge 1$ that doesn't happen for x in [0,1] is this a typo?

Comment: Why this?because cos Takes values Smaller or equal to 1?

Comment: And $x^{2}$also isSmaller than 1 for $x\in[0,1]$

Comment: yes both cosine and $x^2$ are less than or equal to one for all $x \in [0,1]$. So the only possible place they could be equal to one is where $x^2=1$, the values $x=\pm 1$. For $\pm 1$ cosine is again a fraction.

Comment: I understood!thank you!!

Comment: More fundamentally: the function $-x^2 \cos(1/x)$ is negative on $(0, 1]$.

Comment: Pardon?  since $\cos (\pi) = -1$ don't we have that $-x^2 \cos (1/x) >0$ for $x=1/\pi$ (which is certainly in $[0,1]$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is look at when the cosine will be negative.  As we're taking the cosine of $1/x$ we know it will be negative an infinite number of times in $[0,1]$, so we can immediately expect that we're going to need to handle an infinite sum at the end of the calculation.

So: $\cos x$ is negative whenever $\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2} < x < \frac{(4k+3)\pi}{2}, \quad k\in [1,\infty )$, which means that $\cos (1/x)$ is negative whenever $\frac{2}{(4k+1)\pi} < x < \frac{2}{(4k+3)\pi}, \quad k\in (0,1]$.  Since $-x^2 < 0$ for all $x \in (0,1]$ we know that these intervals are the only ones that can contribute to the measure of your set.  Note that $x=0$ does not contribute (because the $x^2$ term dominates) so we can safely omit it from the intervals we're considering.

So the (Lebesgue) measure of the set is now just the sum of the measures of these intervals: ${\cal L}\left( \frac{2}{(4k+1)\pi}, \frac{2}{(4k+3)\pi} \right) = \left| \frac{2}{(4k+3)\pi} - \frac{2}{(4k+1)\pi} \right| = \frac{4}{(4k+1)(4k+3)\pi}$, i.e.
$$ \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+3)}$$
We recognize that sum as being a standard form of the Gregory-Leibniz series, and that is well known to sum to... $\pi/8$.

So, the measure of the set of points of $[0,1]$ where that function is negative is $1/2$.

Comment: I think that $k$ can be 0  too..and the sum of that Serie is $\pi/8$

Comment: it will be $1/2(1-1/3+1/5-.)$ which is $\pi/8$

Comment: And I think that you find out the measure of the Set in which f is positive..Not greater than 1

Comment: Thank-you, you're absolutely right about the start index of $k$ and the sum of the series.  However, $f$ is never greater than 1 (since $|f(x)| = |-x^2 \cos(1/x)| \leq x^2 \leq 1 \quad \forall x\in [0,1]$ -- are you are about the formula $f$ then?

Comment: look what I thought yesterday:$-x^{2}cos(\frac{1}{x}))\ge 1$ is equivalent to:$-cos(\frac{1}{x})\ge 1/(x^{2})\ge 1$, since $x^{2}\le 1$;so $ cos(\frac{1}{x})\le-1$;but the cosine function takes values in $[-1,1]$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So we will have that $cos(\frac{1}{x})=-1$, so $x\in\{1/\pi,1/3\pi,1/5\pi,...\}$. But these values do not verify the given ineguality,so the measure of the set will be indeed 0.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct -- but then the question doesn't make sense.  There are better questions to ask about sets of measure zero, which is why I wondered if there was a typo.  Normally this kind of question wants you to evaluate the size of the intervals, not short-cut the question with a (trivial) observation :)

Comment: It was given by my teacher at measure Theory Course.